# gnome-tweak-tool turned fonts into rectangles

Tags: fonts, gnome-tweak-tool

I installed gnome-tweak-tool to replace the system fonts and add some fonts to `/usr/local/share/fonts/truetype`.

Now, all bold fonts look like rectangles. How can I fix it? Screenshot here:

[image: fonts as rectangles]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same tool change all fonts again to `Ubuntu` or any other standard font that can deal with Ubuntu. Some fonts are not standard, and doesn't cover full set of chars, so when system tries to use a char, for example in bold mode, and that mode does not exist in font, it is shown with a rectangle.

Comment: Changing font back to Ubuntu (even though it looked broken in the list) fixed the issue. Any idea what causes this?

Comment: Yes, Some fonts are not standard, and doesn't cover full set of chars, so when system tries to use a char, for example in bold mode, and that mode does not exist in font, it is shown with a rectangle.

Comment: You should add that comment to your answer. That way, your answer improves and doesn't rely on someone reading the comment.